# Wordpress: How to add URL variables to URL using Rewrite after form GET submit

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, url-parameters

I have a simple search form on my WordPress website that uses method="get" to add variables to my page URL after a user submits the form.

After the form submit, the page URL would look like this: `mydomain.com/for-sale/?category=testcategory&othervariable=xx`

I used the following code to rewrite my URLs to make them more SEO friendly:

```
function category_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'category';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'category_query_vars');

function add_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newrules = array(
        '^for-sale/([^/]*)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=for-sale/&category=$matches[1]',
    );
    $rules = $newrules + $rules;
    return $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Using this code I can visit `mydomain/for-sale/testcategory` and `category` is a query variable I can get. This is working fine.

However, when a user submits the search form (where I set `method='get'`), they are redirected to **mydomain.com/for-sale/?category=testcategory&othervariable=xx** and I would like to have them be redirected to **mydomain.com/for-sale/testcategory/&othervariable=xx**

How could I achieve this? Do I need to edit my `add_rewrite_rules()` function, or could I check if the parameter is added to the URL and then do a redirect?

Answer (score 3):

I've achieved something similar in the past by posting my data to the server which builds the URL and redirects the user. For exmaple:

Frontend form:

```php
<form action="<?= admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ); ?>" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search-redirector">

    <select name="category">
        <option value="testcategory">Test Category</option>
        <option value="anothercategory">Another Category</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="othervariable">

</form>
```

Backend redirect handler:

```php
search_redirect_handler() {

    $payload = $_POST;

    // Remove WordPress action field.
    unset( $payload[ 'action' ] );

    // Get category value.
    $category = !empty( $payload[ 'category' ] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $payload[ 'category' ] ) : null;

    // Base URL.
    $url = home_url( '/for-sale/' );

    // Add category to the URL structure.
    if ( $category ) {
        $url = rtrim( $url, '/' ) . '/' . $category;
        unset( $payload[ 'category' ] );
    }

    // Add remaining fields as query strings.
    $url = add_query_arg( $payload, $url );

    // Send headers.
    status_header( 301 );
    wp_safe_redirect( $url );
    exit;
}

add_action( 'admin_post_search-redirector', 'search_redirect_handler' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_search-redirector', 'search_redirect_handler' );
```

Notice that the `action` field value matches the action name. For more info on this see the documentation here:

- Logged in users: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_action/
- Guest users: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_nopriv_action/

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the great write-up. I have tried your code and after form submit, the category variable is correctly set (I can use `get_query_var('category')`), but the URL is not updated and the other variables are not set. I also noticed a slight error in your code; I assume the final lines needed to be `wp_safe_redirect( $url )` instead of `wp_safe_redirect( $redirect )`, however, still not working after updating this. Still trying to figure out what else I need to change to make it work..

Comment: Hah, I made it work! The form action URL needed an `echo` :-) Now your code is working just fine! (with the little $url edit in the final lines). Thank you so much!